# Converting an int to an IP address

Tags: postgresql

Is there an easy way to convert an int to an IP address in PostgreSQL?  I was able to go from IP to int using this code:

```
SELECT inet '1.2.3.4'-'0.0.0.0'
```

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT 16909060::inet
```

I didn't see anything in the documentation.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT '0.0.0.0'::inet + 16909060
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is trying to select from a table containing IP addresses and the column is defined as a `long`, you can cast to `bigint` and the conversion will work.

```
select '0.0.0.0'::inet + cast(source_ip as bigint) from addresses;
```